# W3TC 0.9.2.3 bug with Wordpress 3.2

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I have a question.

I was in W3 Total Cache 0.9.2.1. 
I just installed W3 Total Cache 0.9.2.3 and I noticed that my pages are not cached.
In `wp-content/w3tc/pgcache`, there are no files. 
Whereas I checked all options... "Page Cache, Minify etc..."

How to solve that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no error notifications in your Admin panel (your installation is complete), you can quickly troubleshoot by temporarily disable all plugins except W3TC and switching to the twentyten theme to see if the problem resolves. Then revert your theme, and re-activate plugins one-by-one until caching fails again and you've found the conflict.